# Change the color of pop up menu's button

Tags: html, css, button

I am  new to css so I cannot figure out the way of changing the color of pop up menus two buttons (Submit and Reset). Both of these are placed at the end of the pop up menu, but are not readable because of the color. I have used this code from [this](https://codepen.io/andrewerrico/pen/Efyrt?editors=1100) site and here the color of button is teal but in my code the button and text color is white and because of this I am unable to read the buttons.

I have tried changing the background color, text color in css but nothing is working

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlUMN.png)

Current Image
[Current image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rIql.png)

I expect the button to be blue

````css
```
.gbtn{
  background: #d0d0d0;
  color: #444444;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.gbtn.btn-estimate{
padding:0 22px;
margin-top:7px;
}
.gbtn.btn-discount{
padding:0 26px;
}
.gbtn:hover{
  background: #fbc443;
  color: #25BCE9;
}
.gbtn:hover span{
color: #25BCE9;
}
.gbtn span{
display: inline-block;
}
button{
/*   border:none;
  background: #25BCE9;
  color: #fff; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;*/
}

#contactForm { 
  display: none;
  z-index: 10000;
  border: 3px solid #25BCE9; 
  padding: 2em;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
}

input{ 
  height: 40px;
  margin: .8em auto;
  font-family: inherit; 
  text-transform: inherit; 
  font-size: inherit;
  display: block; 
  width: 280px; 
  padding: .4em;
}
textarea { 
  height: 80px;
  width:337px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: inherit; 
  text-transform: inherit; 
  font-size: inherit;
  display: block; 
  padding: .4em;
  resize: none;}

.formBtn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: teal;
  color: #fff;
  width: 140px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border: none;
}
````

````html
<div class="block-currency">
<div class="gbtn btn-estimate">
 <div id="contact">Get Quote</div>
</div>
<div id="contactForm">
<h1>Keep in touch!</h1>
<small>We'll get back to you as quickly as possible</small>       
<form action="#">
 <input placeholder="Name" type="text" required />
 <input placeholder="Email" type="email" required />
 <input placeholder="Subject" type="text" required />
 <textarea placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
 <input class="formBtn"  type="submit" />
 <input class="formBtn" type="reset" />
 </form>
 </div>
</div>

Block Currency Code

.block-currency{
position:relative;
float:right;
cursor:pointer;
line-height:50px;
height:50px; 
}
.block-currency:hover ul{
visibility:visible;
top:50px; 
opacity:1;
transition: all 0.3s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
-o-transition: all 0.3s;

}

```
````

Comment: When exactly do you want to change the button color? On hover? It seems that your code is actually working, see: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xeyeJw?editors=1100

Comment: Currently the button has a grey-ish `background-color` and black `color`. I think OP wants the grey to be blue. @LucasNesk

Comment: Hi Amanpreet, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please refer to this [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide as well as [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we are able to provide you with an answer to your question.

Comment: Check the edited question

Comment: @LucasNesk  I want to change the color of buttons that are inside the pop up menu not the color of "Get Quote" button

Comment: @AmanpreetKaur are you changing the button { } style? If so, you may want to change the .formBtn { } style instead, since your pop up buttons are not a button, but a div with a .formBtn class defined.

Comment: @LucasNesk I am not getting your point

Comment: check the image that i have attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.gbtn{
  background: #d0d0d0;
  color: #444444;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.gbtn.btn-estimate{
padding:0 22px;
margin-top:7px;
}
.gbtn.btn-discount{
padding:0 26px;
}
.gbtn:hover{
  background: #fbc443;
  color: #25BCE9;
}
.gbtn:hover span{
color: #25BCE9;
}
.gbtn span{
display: inline-block;
}
button{
/*   border:none;
  background: #25BCE9;
  color: #fff; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;*/
}

#contactForm { 
  z-index: 10000;
  border: 3px solid #25BCE9; 
  padding: 2em;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  top:0%;
  left:0%;
}

input{ 
  height: 40px;
  margin: .8em auto;
  font-family: inherit; 
  text-transform: inherit; 
  font-size: inherit;
  display: block; 
  width: 280px; 
  padding: .4em;
}
textarea { 
  height: 80px;
  width:337px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: inherit; 
  text-transform: inherit; 
  font-size: inherit;
  display: block; 
  padding: .4em;
  resize: none;}

.formBtn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: teal;
  color: #fff;
  width: 140px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-currency">
<div class="gbtn btn-estimate">
 <div id="contact">Get Quote</div>
</div>
<div id="contactForm">
<h1>Keep in touch!</h1>
<small>We'll get back to you as quickly as possible</small>       
<form action="#">
 <input placeholder="Name" type="text" required />
 <input placeholder="Email" type="email" required />
 <input placeholder="Subject" type="text" required />
 <textarea placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
 <input class="formBtn"  type="submit" />
 <input class="formBtn" type="reset" />
 </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have updated the code and I think this can work for you if this now working then please update the code then I can help you.

Comment: please check my edited code your button color is showing correct and alignment also correct. now you tell what you want in that.

Comment: I want submit and reset text in white color and in center of the button

Comment: have you seen my code in code snippet? the buttons view is same as you are asking please check.

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiest way is to add IDs to the input elements:

```
<input id="submitButton"class="formBtn" type="submit" />
<input id="resetButton"class="formBtn" type="reset" />
```

and change their color by targeting directly:

```
#submitButton {
  background: blue;
}
#resetButton {
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Color of the button is blue but now the text is not showing. Can you please edit your comment

Comment: Hello @Hvitis Can you edit you question. I cant see the text and tried to use color: #fff; its not working